# How to get the cursor color?

Tags: java

Is that possible to get any kind of color information about the cursor? 
The reason I'm asking is since my cursor color/image is changing at some point and I need to be able to determine when it happens.

Comment: if you change the cursor that's the time it happens

Comment: @FastSnail I'm not changing the cursor, it's being changed by itself. It's a bot I'm making for a game.

Comment: so you want to determine the change from another application?

Comment: @FastSnail The cursor is moving around the screen perfectly, everything is working fine but in some point the cursor color/image is changed and I would like to know when it happens. So is there anyway to get information about the cursor in a specific moment?